# Digital output drive signal integrity

Tags: digital-logic, impedance

I am designing a PCB with the [ICS-43434](https://invensense.tdk.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/DS-000069-ICS-43434-v1.2.pdf), and would like to do, at least, some simple signal integrity simulations. I asked the manufacturer for impedance, IBIS or V/I curves, but they do not have that data available.

The PCB needs some distance between the mcu and microphone, probably 30cm. The SD clock speed is about 3MHz.

I will connect the SD pin to the MCU input using a 50 ohm pcb-trace line, but how do I simulate the output impedance of the SD pin. ?

From the datasheet, the digital output is specified as below.

[image]

Comment: [\$I^2S\$ specification](https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/BreakoutBoards/I2SBUS.pdf)

Comment: I think you may have an X-Y problem, and don't need to know the output strength and simulate it. Did you read the application note how to connect the microphone? It has examples and recommendations about wire lengths, source termination resistors and buffering the signals. While these don't give an answer how to simulate the data output pin, it still answers how to connect it without the need to simulate it. Also, this clearly is not a device meant to drive a considerable length of transmission line, so if the strength is unknown, the easy answer is just to put a buffer.

Comment: Yes, have read the app note. But it just mentions 20-100 ohm source termination maybe necessary, if need to drive lines longer than 15cm. I need maybe 30cm or more, so would like to verify the design, and be able to calculate optimum source termination resistor.